# Use multiple embeddings with the Transformer architecture

Tags: neural-networks, transformer, embeddings

In their [article](https://openai.com/blog/musenet/) about their system "*MuseNet*" OpenAI state the following:

> Embeddings
>
> We added several different kinds of embeddings to give the model more
> structural context. In addition to the standard positional embeddings,
> we added a learned embedding that tracks the passage of time in a
> given sample. This way, all of the notes that sound at the same time
> are given the same timing embedding. We then add an embedding for each
> note in a chord (this mimics relative attention, since it will be
> easier for the model to learn that note 4 needs to look back at note
> 3, or else at note 4 of the previous chord). Finally, we add two
> structural embeddings which tell the model where a given musical
> sample is within the larger musical piece. One embedding divides the
> larger piece into 128 parts, while the second encoding is a countdown
> from 127 to 0 as the model approaches the (end) token.

I was wondering how to implement and make use of multiple different embeddings for the Transformer architecture. At the moment, the only things that come to my mind would be to sum the embeddings in a similar fashion as is done with the positional encoding, or to somehow concatenate them, where (if the embeddings are of length `l` each) the final embeddings would be of length `2l` for each of the elements.